# No puedo borrar el historial de navegacion en ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Inyecto los modulos en el app.js que es el principal, pero cuando quiero agregar el controlador de ***HistorialApp*** dentro de cualquiera de los templates de los menús sale algún error, o no carga la vista del menú correspondiente.

### Librerias en el HEAD

```
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-Cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="App/login.js"></script>
    <script src="App/historial.js"></script>
    <script src="App/ExitApp.js"></script>
```

### App.js

```
angular.module('unicesarApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'Historial', 'Salida'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
       cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
       cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
  });        
});
```

### historial.js

```
angular.module('Historial', ['ionic'])
       .controller('HistorialApp', HistorialApp);
HistorialApp.$inject = ['$ionicHistory', '$state'];
function HistorialApp($ionicHistory, $state){
    if ($state.is('menuestu') || $state.is('menuprof')) {   
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    }
}
```

### Menu HTML

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" align-title="center">
    <p class="title">Menu Estudiante</p>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-view>    
    <ion-content has-header="true"> 
        <div class="container" ng-controller="HistorialApp">
           <!--Contenido-->
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

### login.js

```
angular.module('unicesarApp', ['ionic'])
           .controller('formulario', formulario)
           .service('obtenerDatos', obtenerDatos)
           .config(config);
    config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
                 $stateProvider
                        //Ingreso
                        .state('login', {
                            url: '/login',
                            templateUrl: "Templates/login.html",
                            controller: "formulario"
                        })                 
                        .state('Loading',{
                             url: '/loading',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/loading.html"
                        })
                        //Estudiante
                        .state('menuestu',{
                             url: '/menuestu',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/menuestu.html"
                        })
                        .state('perfilestu',{
                             url: '/perfilestu',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/perfilestu.html"
                        })
                        .state('horarioestu',{
                             url: '/horarioestu',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/horarioestu.html"
                        })                 
                        .state('calificaciones',{
                             url: '/calificaciones',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/calificaciones.html"
                        })
                        .state('calendarioestu',{
                             url: '/calendarioestu',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/calendarioestu.html"
                        })
                        //Profesor
                        .state('menuprof',{
                             url: '/menuprof',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/Docente/menuprof.html"
                        })
                        .state('perfilprof',{
                             url: '/perfilprof',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/Docente/perfilprof.html"
                        })
                        .state('horarioprof',{
                             url: '/horarioprof',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/Docente/horarioprof.html"
                        })        
                        .state('grupos',{
                             url: '/grupos',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/Docente/grupos.html"
                        })  
                        .state('calendarioprof',{
                             url: '/calendarioprof',
                             templateUrl: "Templates/Docente/calendarioprof.html"
                        });
    };
```

### ExitApp.js

Utilizar el botón de retroceso en android para salir de la app al estar en las vistas de uno de los dos menús

```
angular.module('Salida', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    var closeApp = false;
    $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function ($state, $cordovaToast) {
            if ($state.is('menuestu') || $state.is('menuprof')) {
                    if (closeApp === true) {
                        navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
                else {
                        closeApp = true;
                        $timeout(function () {
                            closeApp = false;
                        }, 2000);
                        $cordovaToast.show('Presione nuevamente para salir', 'long', 'bottom');
                }
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola Pedro que error obtienes?

Comment: No carga las vista de los menús, no se si esta mal inyectado, o el orden del archivo en al cabecera no es el correcto, o si no no borra el historial simplemente

Comment: Hola Pedro. Con el código que pones es poco probable que funcione ya que no veo el fichero de las rutas(con ui-router) por ninguna parte. Te faltó ponerlo o no lo has escrito?

Comment: @devconcept segun el ionic bundle tra todo compacto por asi decirlo, y puedo usar el ui-router y funciona

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales No fue eso lo que me refería. En algún lugar tienes que declarar tus rutas usando la sintaxis de `ui-router` y `$stateProvider.state('nombre estado', { ..config..});`

Comment: Disculpa @devconcept, despues que comente me di cuenta de lo que estabas haciendo la referencia a el codigo de como tengo organizadas las rutas, ya edite la pregunta y puse el codigo de las rutas, espero te sirva

Comment: @devconcept ya coloque tambien el codigo para salir usando el boton de atras en android que lo hago pero no me funciona

Answer (score 1):

Pedro!, el error es el orden en que estas inyectando las dependencias de tus archivos `js`

Tu dices

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="App/login.js"></script>
<script src="App/historial.js"></script>
<script src="App/ExitApp.js"></script>
```

Sin embargo, `app.js` tiene una inyeccion de dependencia a `'Historia'`, cosa que aun no existe porque esta por debajo.

Lo correcto seria :

```
<script src="App/historial.js"></script>
<script src="App/ExitApp.js"></script> 
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="App/login.js"></script>
```